# How to call inputTask from within another inputTask?

Tags: sbt

In a `inputTask` I'm *programmatically* calling another `inputTask`, e.g. `testOnly`, with parameter string as follows:

```
val readParams = inputKey[Unit]("reads version")
readParams := {
  ... // here some Parser code
  val a = "*OnlyThisClassPls*"
  testOnly.toTask(a)
}
```

Unfortunately instead of result I get an exception `Illegal dynamic reference`. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved my problem.

1. I created a method which converts *testOnly* inputTask to dynamic task (*taskDyn*) with parameter

`def testOnlyWithDynamicParams(params: String) = Def.taskDyn {
    (testOnly in Test).toTask(params)
}`

2. I defined an dynamic input task (*inputTaskDyn*) which uses method to convert and **evaluate**s value at the end

`readParams :=  Def.inputTaskDyn {
... // here some Parser code
    val paramsForTestOnly = " *OnlyThisClassPls*"
    testOnlyWithDynamicParams(paramsForTestOnly)
}.evaluated`

I'm not sure if it is a best way but it works for me. If you know the better solution please correct me.

Comment: No, this is the correct way to go.   The Dynamic-vs-static reference thing is about knowing dependencies A-priori in sbt (via sbt inspect).   What you want to do is possible, it's just made harder because sbt doesn't know about the dependency graph until runtime now.